# IBM WESB/WAS JCA security configuration

Tags: java, websphere, jca, cics

I'm working with IBM tools. I have a Websphere ESB (WESB) and a CICS transaction gateway (CTG). The basic set-up is as follows:

A SOAP service needs data from CICS. The SOAP-service is connecting to service bus (WESB) to handle data and protocol transformation and then WESB calls the CTG which in turn calls CICS and the reply is handled vice verse (synchronously). WESB calls the CTG using Resource Adapter and JCA connector (or CICS adapter as it is called in WESB). Now, I have all the pieces in place and working.

My question is about the security, and even though I'm working with WESB, the answer is probably the same as in Websphere Application Server (WAS). The Resource Adaper is secured using JAAS - J2C authentication data. I have configured the security using J2C authentication data entry, so basically I have a reference in the application I'm running and at runtime the application does a lookup for the security attributes from the server. So basically I'm always accessing the CICS adapter with the same security reference.

> My problem is that I need to access the resource in more dynamic way
>   in the future. The security cannot be welded into the application
>   anymore but instead given as a parameter.

**Could some WESB or WAS guru help me out, how this could be done in WESB/WAS exactly?**

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate a bit further? I don't work with CTG but I believe it is no different from other resources such as JDBC or JMS resource.

On the CTG resource adapter, you have identified credentials that are used for all calls to the CICS.

This is similar to what we do when we work with a Data Source and this approach is agreeable to most people.

I do not see how the J2C credential is welded to the application. The configuration is done @ WAS/WESB. The application would simply work with the JNDI resources on the server to which the J2C aliases are configured.

If you elaborate on the dynamic requirement folks can help out.

HTH

Manglu

Comment: Sure! It's not really the CTG, that's the problem. As you said before, it doesn't differ what resource is being used; DS, CICS...all the same. But the thing is with the WESB or actually with its IDE, the WID (Websphere Integration Developer) that is restricting (or at least confusing me) me from implementing a proper java-solution. What WID offers is this: http://d.pr/MKwX and the J2C authentication data entry maps to uid and passw at WESB/WAS like here: http://d.pr/QwQf  Now the J2C dataentry should some way have to be given as a parameter or an alternative solution should be found.

Comment: I still don't see the problem. In a DS you create a identity to act as the credentials to the database. The credentials are created as a JAAS alias which is the J2C entry that you have mentioned. How does that become a constraint in WID. I am happy to help you. I understand this space WESB/WPS pretty well so i am sure i can help you if you can make this a bit clearer to me.